# React useContext() always returning initial value in different children

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-context

I need to share global variables through multiple components, and it seems that my context is not working as expected.

I declared in a seperated file `globalContext.tsx` :

```
export type GlobalContent = {
  entities: entity[]
  setEntities:(c: entity[]) => void,
  pallets: string[],
  setPallets:(c: string[]) => void,
}
export const GlobalContext = createContext<GlobalContent>({
    entities: [], // set a default value
    setEntities: () => {},
    pallets: [],
    setPallets: () => {}
})
```

Then, initialize and my values in my App.tsx, then wrapping all my tree in the Provider  :

```
function App() {
  // Init global variables, accessible everywhere using useContext hook
  const [entities, setEntities] = useState<entity[]>([])
  const [pallets, setPallets] = useState<string[]>(["hello"])
  let defaultGlobals: GlobalContent = { entities, setEntities, pallets, setPallets }

  return (
    <GlobalContext.Provider value={defaultGlobals}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
            <Route path="/picking" element={<Picking/>}/>
            <Route path="/control" element={<Control/>}/>
            <Route path="/place" element={<Place/>}/>
            <Route path="*" element={<NotFound/>}/>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </GlobalContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

So, there should be it. Within my components (let's say <Picking/> for example), I can get find back my default values by using the following :

```
const { entities, setEntities, pallets, setPallets } = useContext(GlobalContext)
```

But when I grab this data in another component (<Control/> or <Place/>) using :

```
const { entities, setEntities, pallets, setPallets } = useContext(GlobalContext)
```

I keep getting the default value (a.k.a. the "defaultGlobals", with ["hello"] array).

I tried changing my `entities` or `pallets` content using the corresponding setters, and the variables extracted from the useContext are definitively independant from a component to another.
Still getting default values at first.

Seems something is breaking the context or I am doing something wrong here.
Any help ?

Here's a link to a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-sky-jlud9m?file=/src/App.tsx).

Example consumer:

```
export default function Home() {
  const { entities, setEntities, pallets, setPallets } = useContext(
    GlobalContext
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <a href="/other">Move to Other</a>
      <h1>Home component</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setPallets([...pallets, "newPallet"])}>
        Add pallet
      </button>
      {pallets.map((pallet) => {
        return <p>{pallet}</p>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `["hello"]` is the default `pallets` state value, so why *wouldn't* another context consumer see that value? I don't see any issue with the code you've shared so I'm thinking if you are seeing something unusual/unexpected it is occurring elsewhere. Can you more clearly explain the perceived issue and exact steps to reproduce, and what you are expecting to see?

Comment: Sorry if it is not clear. My objective here is to use global variables using context. My <Picking/> component is pushing data in the `pallets` and `entities` variables (using the corresponding useState setters). Tell me if I am wrong, but for me, I should be able to see these data in my other components, due to the sharing context. But in my other components, I keep getting the default value and I am not able to see any modification the "global variables"

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I don't see any overt issue(s) with the code you've shared though. Could you try to create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: Yes of course ! Here is a link : https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-sky-jlud9m?file=/src/App.tsx
I created 2 very basic components grabbing the global context, editing data and displaying it.
Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pallets` state and React context value are updating just fine. The issue is that you are using raw anchor tags (`<a />`) to navigate between pages and this is reloading the entire page/app. In other words, the app is remounted and React state is reset.

Use the `Link` component to issue declarative navigation actions to move around the app.

Instead of this:

```
<a href="/other">Move to Other</a>
```

Import and use the `Link` component:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

...

<Link to="/other">Move to Other</Link>
```

[image: Edit react-usecontext-always-returning-initial-value-in-different-children]

[image]
[image]
[image]